# PhpStorm can't highlight the file

Tags: phpstorm

When I write JavaScript in PhpStorm the `articleList.js` file looks great but `list.js` become like plain text.

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the file associations in the settings, perhaps you have associated `list.js` with the plain text file type?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I found list.js been add in file types->text type, I remove it then it's works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if `list.js` is added to text file patterns in **Preferences | Editor | File types -> Text file type**. Removing this pattern should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! list.js is in Text type, I remove it then it's works!